Mouse cursor rapidly switching between arrow pointer and link (hand) cursor
Trying to identify a problem on MacBook pro 2021 where the mouse cursor is rapidly switching between the arrow pointer and link cursor (hand) or I-beam cursor in browsers, text editors, and other applications. This occurs when the window is in focus and the mouse cursor is moved across the screen -- please see the screen recordings:


Current OS version is 14.7 but the behavior has occurred at least since 13.x and likely prior.
Any known fixes or steps to further diagnose? There are mentions of this on other discussion forums but none I could find with this exact behavior. This bug report for a different application describes my problem most closely: https://github.com/keepassxreboot/keepassxc/issues/3595.
What I've observed:

Seems to occur when multiple windows of a given application are spread across different "Spaces" in macOS. * As shown in the second screen recording, the cursor gets buggy at the point where the Firefox window in screen 3 is partially "overlapping" another Firefox window in screen 9.
I've struggled to replicate this behavior consistently and the buggy behavior seems to emerge on its own after a certain amount of time. It is possible that resizing windows will also initiate the behavior.
As mentioned, most commonly occurs with the Firefox browser and Sublime text editor presumably because those are the most used apps but I've observed this with other browsers, the Mac calendar apps and others.
Same behavior with external pointer (Logitech track ball) or built-in Mac touch pad. Same with external monitor plugged in or with built-in display.

I've attempted without success:

to boot in safe mode -- behavior persisted.
this about:config change in Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/961649


Please test with all peripherals disconnected. Also enable the Guest account and test while logged in as Guest.

@LincDavis : appreciate the suggestions but no luck: I tried without peripherals (no monitor/input devices) and on Guest account. Neither solved the issue. I'm likely to reach out to apple support, again--perhaps having it documented here will help narrow down the cause.

If you're triggering an obscure OS bug, you might get rid of it by upgrading to Sequoia, unless something in your workflow prevents that.

Appreciate the suggestion but upgrading to 15.1.1 didn't resolve this.

Did you contact Apple Support?
